# Working twitter-typeahead example?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-typeahead

I'm trying to install the `twitter-typeahead-rails` gem into my app. I've followed several different tutorials but all of them result in errors.

Does anyone have a working example of this gem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify gem as dependency in your `Gemfile`:

```
# Gemfile

gem 'bootstrap-multiselect-rails'
```

Require typeahead files in your manifest:

```
// app/assets/javascripts/application.js

//= require twitter/typeahead
//= require twitter/typeahead/bloodhound
```

Javascript:

```
// app/assets/javascripts/models_controller.js

// initialize bloodhound engine
var bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function (d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

  // sends ajax request to /typeahead/%QUERY
  // where %QUERY is user input
  remote: '/typeahead/%QUERY', 
  limit: 50
});
bloodhound.initialize();

// initialize typeahead widget and hook it up to bloodhound engine
// #typeahead is just a text input
$('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
});

// this is the event that is fired when a user clicks on a suggestion
$('#typeahead').bind('typeahead:selected', function(event, datum, name) {
  doSomething(datum.id);
});
```

View:

```
<-- app/views/models/whatever.html.erb -->

<input type="text" id="typeahead">
```

Routes:

```
# config/routes.rb

get 'typeahead/:query' => 'models#typeahead'
```

Controller:

```
# app/controllers/models_controller.rb

def typeahead
  render json: Model.where(name: params[:query])
end

## note:  the above will only return exact matches.
## depending on the database being used,
## something else may be more appropriate.
## here is an example for postgres
## for case-insensitive partial matches:

def typeahead
  render json: Model.where('name ilike ?', "%#{params[:query]}%")
end
```

GET request to /typeahead/%QUERY returns json in the form of:

```
[
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
     "name": "bar",
     "id": "2"
  }
]
```

Comment: It's javascript, so drop it in the javascript file that corresponds to your controller or whatever is appropriate for your app.  Make sure it runs _after_ the DOM is ready.  If you're using turbolinks (rails 4+): `$(document).on('page:change', function() { // DOM is ready in here });`.

Comment: What do you have in your view?

Comment: All you need in the view is a text input.  I updated my answer for completeness.

Comment: Wait, so how do I link that to actual data to search through?

Comment: I updated the answer to include example route and controller code.  The line `remote: '/typeahead/%QUERY', ` tells typeahead to make an ajax request to `/typeahead/%QUERY` to fetch data based on user input.

Comment: Does that work for you? I mean with just that code, does the text input bring up suggestions as you type?

Comment: Yes, this code is taken form an app that I maintain (with some variable and field names that are specific to the app changed to be more generic).

Comment: I updated my answer to include that typeahead/bloodhound files need to be required in `application.js` manifest.  I can't think of any other relevant code that I haven't provided an example of.

Comment: @ihaztehcodez i have followed your directions and am trying to implement typeahead for multiple attributes.However i am not getting any json response when putting in my url.Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28658253/815929

Comment: This is a great answer. One thing that may not be obvious: the `typeahead` method in the controller needs to handle some kind of wildcard/substring search. As is, you're probably going to get an empty result. I suspect this is the problem that @rnjai is encountering.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @klenwell, that's a good point.  I guess when I was creating a generic example that got lost in translation.  I updated my answer to point that out and give a better example that is specific to postgres.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is not completely correct.

There seem to be 2 different gems doing roughly the same thing:

`bootstrap-multiselect-rails` is currently on version 0.9.9 in the gem repository and has a different asset require structure as mentioned in the post. This gem's assets need to be included as:

```
In application.js:
//= require bootstrap-multiselect

In application.css:
*= require bootstrap-multiselect
```

More on Git: https://github.com/benjamincanac/bootstrap-multiselect-rails

Alternatively, there is the `twitter-typeahead-rails` gem, currently on version 0.11.1 which seem to need to be used and included as described in the rest of the accepted answer.

More on Git: https://github.com/yourabi/twitter-typeahead-rails

Both gems seem to be last updated about 5-6 months ago at the moment of writing this.

Finally, the remote URL specified in the Bloodhound JS is incorrect:

```
remote: '/typeahead/%QUERY'
```

Needs to be

```
remote: {url: '/typeahead/%QUERY', wildcard: '%QUERY'}
```

Hopefully this helps someone