# Typeahead Bloodhound Rails with pg_search

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I am using this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102146/working-twitter-typeahead-example/28102342#28102342) to try and implement Twitter Typeahead for my rails app and I have also tried implementing the [Github](https://github.com/yourabi/twitter-typeahead-rails) readme but there is no text suggestions when I type into the textbox.

My Controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def typeahead

    @vn = Vn.search_by_name(params[:search])
    render json: @vn.results
  end
end
```

**My route**

```
get 'typeahead/:query' => 'pages#typeahead'
```

**Application.js**

```
//= require twitter/typeahead
//= require twitter/typeahead/bloodhound
```

**pages_controller.js in assets/javascripts**

```
var bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function (d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

  // sends ajax request to /typeahead/%QUERY
  // where %QUERY is user input
  remote: '/typeahead/%QUERY', 
  limit: 50
});
bloodhound.initialize();

// initialize typeahead widget and hook it up to bloodhound engine
// #typeahead is just a text input
$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
});

// this is the event that is fired when a user clicks on a suggestion
$('.typeahead').bind('typeahead:selected', function(event, datum, name) {
  doSomething(datum.id);
});
```

**My view**

```
   <%= form_tag(search_path, :method => "get", class: "navbar-form", id: "search-form") do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control padding-search typeahead", placeholder: "Search" %>   
      <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn btn-primary padding-search") do %>          
   <% end %>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yeah I did, I'll post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the settings that allowed Typeahead suggestions to work for me after troubleshooting for awhile.

Coffeescript

```
jQuery -> 
  users = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  limit: 10,
  #local http://localhost:3000/json/vns.json
  remote: {url:'/typeahead/%QUERY'
   , wildcard: '%QUERY'
   }
  })

  users.initialize();
  $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
      name: "mysearch"
      source: users.ttAdapter()
  })
```

Controller

```
    def typeahead    
    @vn = Vn.search_by_name(params[:search])
    @name = @vn.select('name').map(&:name)

    render json: @name
  end
  //Under Routes
  get 'typeahead/:search' => 'pages#typeahead'
  //View
 <%= form_tag(search_path, :method => "get", class: "navbar-form", id: "search-form" ) do %>
              <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control typeahead", placeholder: "Search " %>
              <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn btn-primary padding-search") do %>
                  <i class="fa fa-search 6x"></i>
              <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Do you know what the `wildcard: '%QUERY'` does?  I read the api but still don't understand.

Comment: I'm not too sure but I got it from the main website. https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/